# Https to Http redirect in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, web, https

We have a website and some of the pages are using `https` and those pages kept in `magic` folder.

https enabling and port number is configured in web.config for a site.

However if the user trying to access magic folder contents using `http`, we need to redirect back to **https** and vise versa

***Ex Case 1:***  Working for `http to https`

`http://mysite/magic-look` to `https://mysite/magic-look`

Here, we used

```
<urlMappings>
  <add url="~/magic-look" mappedUrl="~/magic/look.aspx"/>
  <add url="~/help" mappedUrl="~/Help/default.aspx"/>
```

In Global.asax

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
    var secPort = String.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["securePort"]) ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["securePort"]);
    var secProtocolEnabled = String.IsNullOrEmpty(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["useSecure"]) ? false : true;

    bool isSecureUrl = (url.IndexOf("/magic/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0) ? true : false;

    if (url.IndexOf(".aspx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    {
        url = url.Replace(":" + secPort, "");

        if (isSecureUrl && secProtocolEnabled)
        {

            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port != secPort)
            {
                //change .aspx page back to original SEO friendly URL and redirect
                url = url.Replace(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath, HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);                    
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(Regex.Replace(url, "http", "https", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
            }
        }
        else
        {


            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port == secPort && !isSecureUrl)
            {
                //cause infinite loop
               url = url.Replace(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath, HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl); 
               var targetUrl = Regex.Replace(url, "https", "http", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);                   
               HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(targetUrl);                        
            }                
        }            
    }
}
```

**Non https page accessed using Https, Not working, infinite loop**

***ISSUE:***  Not working for `https to http`

`https://mysite/help` to `http://mysite/help`

It gives `infinite loop.. keep redirecting to *https://mysite/help*`

```
https://mysite/help --> 302 Found
https://mysite/Help --> 302 Found 
https://mysite/Help --> 302 Found 
https://mysite/Help --> 302 Found .............
```

**UPDATE:**

If it remove this, it works fine.

```
  url = url.Replace(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath, 
         HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
```

But 3 requests instead of 2

```
https://mysite/help --> 302 Found
https://mysite/Help/Default.aspx--> 302 Found 
http://mysite/Help/Default.aspx--> 200 OK
```

However i want SEO friendly url like `http://mysite/Help/`

**UPDATE 2: ROOT CAUSE:**

Whenever the url is `https://../something` and redirecting to `http://../something` is always making request `https://../something`

Comment: Is this ASP.NET web forms or ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Can we see your `AppSettings` from `.config` file?

Comment: @pwdst, its Webforms, if it is mvc i could  have tagged with `asp.net MVC`

Comment: @geedubb, you want to see `securePort, useSecure` values? It got nothing, they are just numbers and flag works fine. Issue is in some logical problem in redirection loop

Comment: Can you fix the bugs on your own program ? Use some tested library like: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5523/Switching-Between-HTTP-and-HTTPS-Automatically

Comment: @Billa, you don't know that -1 was Aristos. It could of been anyone.

Comment: @Liam, ok got it. But whats wrong in asking this question? If i know everything, why should I ask in SO? :(

Comment: @Billa Because this question is not going to help any one else beside you. Have to do with design error on your logic - a bug, that you can solve by stepping and debugging your code. If you can not solve bugs, have all the tools, imaging how difficult is some else make debugging in their mind to find what in your design contains the bug. And what are going to do with more difficult and complex bugs ?

Comment: @Billa, just for your information there is a a "webforms" tag - ASP.NET encompasses both WebForms and MVC equally (Microsoft are currently keen on the concept "One ASP.NET"), so the lack of "asp.net-mvc" tag didn't infer web forms *quite* as strongly as you might have thought - although I did think that was probably the case. In either case, always good to be sure - thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

I just re-factored your code and used string.Format method to build url

```
private static string GetMyUrl(string securePort, string useSecure, Uri uri)
{
    int secPort;
    if (!int.TryParse(securePort, out secPort)) secPort = 0;
    bool secProtocolEnabled = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(useSecure);

    bool shouldBeSecureUrl = uri.AbsolutePath.Contains("/magic/");

    if (!uri.AbsolutePath.EndsWith(".aspx")) return uri.AbsoluteUri;

    bool forceSecure = (shouldBeSecureUrl && secProtocolEnabled);
    string url = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}{3}",
        forceSecure
            ? "https"
            : "http",
        uri.Host,
        forceSecure && secPort != 0
            ? string.Format(":{0}", secPort)
            : string.Empty,
        uri.PathAndQuery);
    return url;
}

protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = GetMyUrl(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["securePort"],
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["useSecure"], HttpContext.Current.Request.Url);
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri != url) HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

You can test your addresses.  Samples...

```
Console.WriteLine(GetMyUrl("8484","t", new Uri("https://www.contoso.com/catalog/shownew.aspx?date=today")));
Console.WriteLine(GetMyUrl("8484","t", new Uri("https://www.contoso.com:8484/magic/shownew.aspx?date=today")));
Console.WriteLine(GetMyUrl("8484","t", new Uri("http://www.contoso.com:8080/magic/shownew.aspx?date=today")));
Console.WriteLine(GetMyUrl("","t", new Uri("https://www.contoso.com/catalog/shownew.aspx?date=today")));
Console.WriteLine(GetMyUrl("8484","", new Uri("https://www.contoso.com/catalog/shownew.aspx?date=today")));
```

Comment: Your code goes infinite loop for even a normal page.. `http-->http` itself infinite redirect

Comment: Now clicking on secure pages url changes to `https://site:8080/magic/look.aspx` and getting new error `Firefox is configured to use a proxy server that is refusing connections`. This condition was working in my old code. The actual url should be used in address bar `https://site/magic-look/`

Comment: @Billa use the test cases to figure what is the problem on your end out, I believe you got your answer. ;-)

Comment: Yes got you.. Now i realized we got some url rewrite which internally made a problem. resolved now and i updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Finally found that we have url rewrite enabled, so just added config entry, works for all scenario

```
<configSections>
 <section name="URLRewriteConfiguration" 
   type="MyAssembly.Routing.URLRewriteConfiguration, MyAssembly.Routing, 
   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
</configSections>

<URLRewriteConfiguration>
<Routes>
  <add Pattern="/help/default.aspx" PermanentRedirect="true" Replacement="/help"/>
```

and removed

```
 url = url.Replace(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath, HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
```